# Showing Interstitial Ad in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is this correct...It showing only test ads but It's not showing real ads. I won't know whether the following method is correct or wrong for InterstitialAd.I've imported `admob` package and configured AndroidManifest.xml as following.

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-############~#######"/>
```

Main.dart

```
    static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
        testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
        nonPersonalizedAds: true,
        keywords: <String>['Game', 'Mario'],
      );


    InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;



    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId:"ca-app-pub-##############~########");

     } 



    @override
      void dispose() {
        _interstitialAd.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }


 InterstitialAd createInterstitialAd() {
    return InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-#############/#######",
      //Change Interstitial AdUnitId with Admob ID
        targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          print("IntersttialAd $event");
        });
  }
```

Ad is triggered using button

```
onPressed:(){

    createInterstitialAd()
    ..load()
    ..show();

}
```

Comment: If it's displaying test ads it will probably work on production. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You've setup test devices in your targetingInfo.

As long as all your ids from admob are from the console (production not test codes) then when this runs on actual devices other than the one you’re testing on. It should work fine. It may take some time before actual ads get populated on a new app.

Comment: You've setup test devices in your targetingInfo.

As long as all your ids from admob are from the console (production not test codes) then when this runs on actual devices other than the one you’re testing on. It should work fine. It may take some time before actual ads get populated on a new app. So don’t worry about it because it probably will work.

Comment: So I don't have change anything right? Do I have to remove this line? `testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,`

Comment: No you don't have to remove this line, as you're testing on your device. You don't need to do anything. It should work fine when its on your users devices in the real world. I just updated my answer to best reflect the answer to your question. Thanks